# how to mod rewrite unicode byte sequence for the multibyte hyphen character

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have case where some adobe pdf files format the hyphen character as %E2%80%90.  See http://forums.adobe.com/message/2807241 this is caused by the Calibri font I guess.

So these pdf files have been released and the links don't work So I thought mod rewrite would come to the rescue.

I followed this post here [mod_ReWrite to remove part of a URL](https://serverfault.com/questions/218072/mod-rewrite-to-remove-part-of-a-url) but I can't seem to search for the % characters according to this question.

Is there anything else I can do?

Here is the rewrite rule I want to use:

```
RewriteRule ^foo%(.+)bar  /foo-bar [L,R=301]
```

I also tried this and it doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^foo%E2%80%90bar  /foo-bar [L,R=301]
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279681/mod-rewrite-replace-underscores-with-dashes), I was able to come up with this `.htaccess` rule which fixed my own unicode-hyphen-links-in-pdfs problem:

```
# for janky pdfs with links using unicode hyphens
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)\x25E2\x2580\x2590([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)\x25E2\x2580\x2590([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> ... it is applied to the (%-decoded) URL-path of the request ...

So use the actual character in a UTF-8-encoded file instead.

Comment: Is there any way for it to see the difference between foo%E2%80%90bar and foo-bar?  If not I might be out of luck.

Comment: ... But you're looking for foo‐bar...

Comment: http://www.example.com/foo%E2%80%90bar comes up with a page not found error.  while http://www.example.com/foo-bar works fine.  I guess I could just move the page to foo-bar-v1 and then redirect all foo-bar to foo-bar-v1.